# Error:1104 uafxcwd.lib/nafxcwd.lib missing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 xpress for desktop application. To use mfc framework also installed wdk 7.1 and include files and libraries. After that I executed the code:

```
#include"afxwin.h"

struct CSimpleApp : public CWinApp
{
  BOOL InitInstance() { return TRUE; }
};
CSimpleApp theApp;
```

But it is showing error:

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'uafxcwd.lib'

I tried with both shared and static mfc library with both character set i.e. unicode and multi byte.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio "Express" versions do not provide MFC.

Comment: ya thats y installed wdk7.1 and configured. do u know what is wdk?